# Foursquare API place icon background color

Tags: ios, iphone, foursquare

I have been using `Foursuare API` to list nearby places in my IOS app.Following is the `url` to get the icon image:

```
https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/default_64.png
```

Response is white icon with white background color. So its not seen in my App. Please suggest me a way to get the icon with different colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert `bg` into the URL, you can get a version of the icon with a background color: https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/default_bg_64.png

See our full [category documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/category) for more info!